# Tagger 4.0 and EE 3.4.1 - Can't add tags?

Tags: ee3, tags, devdemon-tagger, tagger

I've added Tagger 4.0 to my system, I've added the tag field to my channel fields and as per the instructions, it says to type a tag and hit enter to save it... Problem is that hitting enter to save the tag submits the form.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with Tagger too - I've experienced this exact same issue too and making sure EE was up to date and re-downloading the latest version of tagger completely removing and reinstalling seemed to fix it for me, but I appreciate that's not helpful if you already have entries with tag data.

Is that something you can try?

Comment: I can't remember what this was for, but I think I found a different way to do it (was about 8 months ago haha)

Comment: Yeah, sorry it wasn't really relevant.  Was just looking around for other issues on Tagger when I saw that and remembered I'd had that too.